# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable, Python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, iteration

I have a made a few posts of the last few days , so thanks for the help so far, all of it is appreciated for helping out a beginner.

Heads Up , I know the code below looks erm very basic and there is probably a lost simpler and more elegant way to achieve what I am attempting, but for now this is the basics I can learn and actually understand to a degree haha.

Just wondering if someone can actually tell me what the error is caused by,on the program output, it seems to run ok sometimes and fail with this error maybe 2 out of 3.

this is still a work in progress project , the main purpose is creating a program that I can automate something I do manually as a learning environment.

Thanks for any Insight.

Program Output

```
Beginning Mining
Opener Created
Opener Headers Added
Url Assigned
HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable
1
Opener Created
Opener Headers Added
Url Assigned
Page Open and Read
90378
 soup assigned to rawdata
 filtered for torType Class
 reassigned to soup to tordata
Links Filtered
Printing Recent Torrents from Filter WebData function
['/the-big-bang-theory-s07e08-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8180359.html', '/the-walking-dead-s04e05-hdtv-x264-2hd-ettv-t8158163.html', '/the-vampire-diaries-s05e07-proper-hdtv-x264-2hd-ettv-t8180537.html', '/the-big-bang-theory-7x7-hdtv-lol-t8141134.html', '/how-i-met-your-mother-s09e09-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8164029.html', '/sons-of-anarchy-s06e10-hdtv-x264-asap-ettv-t8170162.html', '/american-horror-story-s03e06-hdtv-x264-killers-ettv-t8175485.html', '/sleepy-hollow-s01e07-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8164318.html', '/elementary-2x8-hdtv-lol-t8180367.html', '/the-originals-s01e07-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8169688.html', '/the-blacklist-s01e07-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8124923.html', '/modern-family-s05e07-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8175344.html', '/arrow-s02e06-proper-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8179975.html', '/white-collar-s05e05-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8180828.html', '/homeland-s03e07-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-eztv-t8158378.html', '/greys-anatomy-s10e09-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8180608.html', '/how-i-met-your-mother-s09e08-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8124354.html', '/arrow-s02e05-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8135416.html', '/boardwalk-empire-s04e10-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8158693.html', '/the-simpsons-s25e04-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8157997.html', '/modern-family-s05e06-hdtv-x264-asap-eztv-t8061643.html', '/new-girl-s03e07-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8130237.html', '/the-tomorrow-people-us-s01e06-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8174964.html', '/the-walking-dead-s04e04-hdtv-x264-2hd-ettv-t8118639.html', '/supernatural-s09e06-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8169899.html']
Printing newdata which should be Recent Torrents from Filter WebData function
['/the-big-bang-theory-s07e08-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8180359.html', '/the-walking-dead-s04e05-hdtv-x264-2hd-ettv-t8158163.html', '/the-vampire-diaries-s05e07-proper-hdtv-x264-2hd-ettv-t8180537.html', '/the-big-bang-theory-7x7-hdtv-lol-t8141134.html', '/how-i-met-your-mother-s09e09-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8164029.html', '/sons-of-anarchy-s06e10-hdtv-x264-asap-ettv-t8170162.html', '/american-horror-story-s03e06-hdtv-x264-killers-ettv-t8175485.html', '/sleepy-hollow-s01e07-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8164318.html', '/elementary-2x8-hdtv-lol-t8180367.html', '/the-originals-s01e07-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8169688.html', '/the-blacklist-s01e07-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8124923.html', '/modern-family-s05e07-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8175344.html', '/arrow-s02e06-proper-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8179975.html', '/white-collar-s05e05-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8180828.html', '/homeland-s03e07-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-eztv-t8158378.html', '/greys-anatomy-s10e09-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8180608.html', '/how-i-met-your-mother-s09e08-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8124354.html', '/arrow-s02e05-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8135416.html', '/boardwalk-empire-s04e10-hdtv-x264-2hd-eztv-t8158693.html', '/the-simpsons-s25e04-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8157997.html', '/modern-family-s05e06-hdtv-x264-asap-eztv-t8061643.html', '/new-girl-s03e07-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8130237.html', '/the-tomorrow-people-us-s01e06-hdtv-x264-lol-eztv-t8174964.html', '/the-walking-dead-s04e04-hdtv-x264-2hd-ettv-t8118639.html', '/supernatural-s09e06-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t8169899.html']
Mining Ended
Relative Search
Diagnostic line ['*arrow*', '*grimm*', '*elementary*', '*American*Horror*', '*once*Upon*aTime*', '*Agents*of*shield*']
Diagnostic line None
Searching for My Torrents
Reset Vars
Diagnostic line *arrow*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\scratchpad.py", line 121, in <module>
    SearchTorrents(MyPrograms,RecentTorrentLinks)
  File "C:\Python33\scratchpad.py", line 103, in SearchTorrents
    matchobj = fnmatch.filter(TorrentList,item)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\fnmatch.py", line 59, in filter
    for name in names:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Program Code

```
WebUrl = 'http://kickasstorrents.come.in/tv/'
MyPrograms = ['*arrow*','*grimm*','*elementary*','*American*Horror*','*once*Upon*aTime*','*Agents*of*shield*']
loop = 0
RecentTorrentLinks = []



def RetrieveWebData(MyUrl):
    try:
        #create Url Opener
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
            #Diagnostic Line
        print( "Opener Created")
        #Simulation as a browser
        opener.addheaders =[('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
            #Diagnostic Line
        print( "Opener Headers Added")
        url = (MyUrl)
            #Diagnostic Line
        print( "Url Assigned")
        #Open URL and read Data
        page = opener.open(url).read()
            #Diagnostic Line
        print( "Page Open and Read")
            #Diagnostic Line
        print(len(page))
        newdata = FilterWebData(page)
            # Diagnotic Line
        print ("Printing newdata which should be Recent Torrents from Filter WebData function")
        print (newdata)
        return newdata

    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e)
        if e.code == 503:
            print (loop ++ 1)
            RetrieveWebData(WebUrl)
        else:
            print('Error Occured :-' + e + ' Code :- '+ e.code)
            sys.exit()




def FilterWebData(RawData):
    RecentTors = []

    try:

        soup = BeautifulSoup(RawData)
            #Diagnostic Line
        print (" soup assigned to rawdata")

        TorData = soup.find_all("a", {"class" : "torType"})
           #Diagnostic Line
        print (" filtered for torType Class")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(str(TorData))
           #Diagnostic Line
        print (" reassigned to soup to tordata")
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            RecentTors.append(link.get('href'))

           #Diagnostic Line
        print ("Links Filtered")
            # Diagnotic Line
        print ("Printing Recent Torrents from Filter WebData function")
        print (RecentTors)
        return RecentTors

    #Simpler Version of my code by StackOverlfow User
        #TorData = soup.find_all("a", {"class" : "torType", 'href': True})
        #return [link['href'] for link in TorData]

    except OSError as e:
        print("An error occurred during filtering",e)



def SearchTorrents(SearchCrit,TorrentList):
    try:
                    #Diagnostic Line
        print ('Diagnostic line ' + str(SearchCrit))
        print ('Diagnostic line ' + str(TorrentList))
                    #Diagnostic Line
        print ("Searching for My Torrents")
        item = " "
        matchobj = " "
                    #Diagnostic Line
        print ("Reset Vars")

        for item in SearchCrit:
                        #Diagnostic Line
            print ('Diagnostic line ' + item)
            #print ('Diagnostic line ' + str(TorrentList))
            matchobj = fnmatch.filter(TorrentList,item)
            print (matchobj)
    except OSError as e:
        print("An error occurred during searching",e)

    #Diagnostic Line
print ("Beginning Mining")
RecentTorrentLinks = RetrieveWebData(WebUrl)  

            #Diagnostic Line
print ("Mining Ended")

            #Diagnostic Line
print ("Relative Search")
            #Diagnostic Line
#print ("Diagnotic Line TorrentLinks ")
#print (RecentTorrentLinks)

SearchTorrents(MyPrograms,RecentTorrentLinks)

           #Diagnostic Line
print ("Relative Ended")
```

Comment: Ok thanks to the answers, I implementated error checking and I replaced the return in the retreieveweb  function with a global variable , the list was passing around from variable to variable to much, as soon as I took this , maybe incorrect shortcut it seems to be all working 1st time at the moment. thanks for insights and help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TorrentList` is actually `None` which means you cannot iterate over it.

Change this line

```
matchobj = fnmatch.filter(TorrentList,item)
```

to

```
if TorrentList is not None:
    matchobj = fnmatch.filter(TorrentList,item)
else:
    # Throw whatever error/exception you need
```

Comment: Thanks codegeek, I will add that addition, but what I don't understand the list shouldn't be empty as further up the code, it should the generated list, but it seems to turn to none when passed to the search function. appreciated and thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the variable TorrentList is sometimes not a list, but instead is NoneType. So, when you attempt to filter it, it throws the error. You should add a check in your code to make sure it is actually a list before filtering it.

You can see in your output, before the error, these lines are printed:

```
Diagnostic line ['*arrow*', '*grimm*', '*elementary*', '*American*Horror*', '*once*Upon*aTime*', '*Agents*of*shield*']
Diagnostic line None
```

Those are the output of the following lines:

```
print ('Diagnostic line ' + str(SearchCrit))
print ('Diagnostic line ' + str(TorrentList))
```

As you can see, TorrentList prints out 'None', instead of a list. So, as I said above, when you try to filter this on the following line:

```
matchobj = fnmatch.filter(TorrentList,item)
```

it throws the error.

Comment: Thanks forgivenson, I noticed that, but I thought it was a list all the way through, it seems sometimes it changes to none when passing it into the search function, can you advise on how to check if it is a list, if that ok with yourself. Thanks again